# error in get result of listview getSelectedItem()

Tags: java, android

I have an android activity with a listView. When I click an item of the list I want to print the content of what I clicked, so I write this :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(listView.getSelectedItem()!=null)
                {
                    String item = listView.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    Log.d("LIST ITEM", item);
                }




            }
        });
```

But nothing is printed..why ??

Comment: use `position` instead of `listView.getSelectedItem()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
if(listView.getSelectedItem()!=null) {
    String item = listView.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Log.d("LIST ITEM", item);
 }
```

with

```
String item =  adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
Log.d("LIST ITEM", item);
```

Comment: another question..the item that i print is this : ID: ["1"]. If I want to obtain only "1" how can I extract from the string item ?

Comment: post how do you create the adapter

Comment: I resolved with method subString() to extract the internal content of [].

Comment: ok.. If you are happy with that solution. Please accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

+1 for @shayanpourvatan.

In my case `listView.getSelectedItem() ==null` and `adapterView.getSelectedItemPosition() == -1`.

**The only way I can is `((ListView) parent).getAdapter().getItem(position)`**

It seems `select` and `click` are two different thing in Android.